# Is this a one-day value-at-risk?

Tags: finance

Mathematica's help page for StableDistribution (ref/StableDistribution) gives a great way of calculating the value-at-risk using a few lines of code only:

```
log\[ScriptCapitalD] = 
 StableDistribution[1, 1.38, -0.177, -0.006, 0.0297];
VaR = InverseSurvivalFunction[log\[ScriptCapitalD], 0.95];
pointLoss = FinancialData["SP500"] (Exp[VaR] - 1);
```

My question is: is the VaR above a one-day VAR? In other words, what is the time horizon for the VaR? 
Perhaps since the calculation is at 95% level, I can assume that a loss of pointLoss dollars or more  is expected on 1 day out of 20 days (because of 100%-95%= 5% probability). Am I right?

Your help and insights will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I do not quite see what you are trying to do here. One way of approaching this problem would be to fit the stable distribution to one day changes in the S&P index and then calculate the one day quantile that you require. However, you seem already to have a parameterized distribution, from which you calculate the 95th percentile, and then apply this to the index. This looks incorrect to me. Also I do not see why you e to the value of the VaR. Perhaps you have left out some previous steps which might make sense of what you have done.

Comment: What I was trying to get at above is that whether the VaR applies to one day depends on how you calibrate it. I think that the statement "Perhaps since the calculation is at 95% level, I can assume that a loss of pointLoss dollars or more is expected on 1 day out of 20 days (because of 100%-95%= 5% probability)" is incorrect, because it assumes that each day's market movements are statistically independent, which they are not.

Comment: In my view, this isn't actually a Mathematica question, but rather a conceptual question about how Value at Risk works. I suggest that the question is reformulated and referred to the Quantitative Finance stack exchange.

Comment: Much thanks for your comments and correction GerardF123. The reason for Exp[VaR] is because a  parametric fit was applied to logarithmic (in base e) returns. The complete code is from Mathematica help page ref/stableDisribution under Applications and I now quote here:

Assuming daily logarithmic return of the stock market follows a stable distribution, simulate and visualize stock prices over a period of 5 years:
    logReturns = 
  BlockRandom[SeedRandom[2010]; 
   RandomVariate[StableDistribution[1, 1.38, -0.096, -0.001, 0.005], 
    5*365]];

Comment: So, I believe the answer to my question “Is this a one-day value-at-risk?” is YES! That’s because the parametric fit was made to daily logarithmic returns.

Comment: And you are right that my sentence "Perhaps since the calculation..." was incorrect.